# is there away to hide php code in wordpress not to show in PAGES

Tags: php, loop

I added a code in my theme template below the_content tag, meaning I want it displayed only in POST and not in PAGES.

How do I do this??

Example the code shows on domain.com/2012/02/postname/ **and** domain.com/about-us/

I want it only displayed on  domain.com/2012/02/postname/

Comment: add the code in 'single.php' file only

Comment: there are no single.php in this theme, am confused. can you please explain

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: try the folder 'template-parts\post' content.php

Comment: using frontier WordPress theme. besides, I added the code to loop-single.php inside the theme folder

Comment: working.  used this **if (is_singular('post')) {

    //code here

}**

Answer (score 1):

Finally Working.

I used this

```
if (is_singular('post')) {

    // your code after this line or comment

}
```